# Videojs real-time streaming over HTTP not working in Firefox/Opera

Tags: html5-video, real-time, video.js

I am streaming the video of a webcam using VLC. The video codec is h264 and the container format is flv. The video is sent over HTTP/TCP and it must be a real-time application.

When I use Chrome or IExplorer to display the video streaming, it works fine. For example, if the streaming broadcast started 2 minutes before, videojs directly seeks to minute 2 and displays the video at real-time.

But It doesn't happen when using Opera or Mozilla Firefox. In the above case, videojs displays the video starting at minute 0. Since it has no information from minute 0 to minute 2, it shows a static image in that period of time. Then, when it reaches minute 2 it displays the video packets received 2 minutes before...

What could be the reason for the different behaviour between browsers? Is there a way (probably javascript way) to directly seek to the live starting point?

Thank you